# What does const { target: { files } } = event mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, events, destructor

I am using Firebase with React, and using a Firebase File uploader and I'm using a module that uses this syntax

const { target: { files } } = event;

What does that do?

Below is the full code

I tried googling destructuring, but no luck, can someone confirm if it is ?

```
   customOnChangeHandler = (event) => {
        const { target: { files } } = event;
        const filesToStore = [];

        files.forEach(file => filesToStore.push(file));

        this.setState({ files: filesToStore });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const { target: { files } } = event;
// equals to:
// const files = event.target.files;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is [es6 destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) feature, it allows to destruct (pick) a field from an object.